# How to manually install packages for MikTex

Tags: package, miktex

I am using MikTex 2.9 and Texmaker. I need to download packages, such as the sespace package, manually from https://ctan.org/. I have done that and placed the resulting folder in: C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex

Other previously installed packages are in that location and are recognised by MikTex as present.

The setspace folder contains setspace.sty and two test files. However when I compile in Texmaker it doesn't recognise that the package is present, and wants to download it.

Does the .sty file need to go somewhere specific, and how do I find out where that might be, please?

Comment: Do you have the error message?